# Trouble with Toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a main module and another one which creates `Toplevel` object. When I try to call the last from the first module, I don't see `Text` widget or `Button` widget but geometry and title are working:

[image: working]

When trying to call the second module as main I see two windows, the first with geometry and title and the second with `Button`, `Text` and wrong title(tk).

[image: two windows]

Here is my main module

```
import tkinter as tk
from Calendar import show_calendar
from Notes_widget import show_notes_widget

class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_main()

        # Настройка фрейма на главном окне
    def init_main(self):
        self.btn1 = tk.Button(text='Выбрать дату', width=20, height=3, command=show_calendar)
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(text='Ввести задачу', width=20, height=3, command=show_notes_widget)

        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn2.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создание главного окна
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Создание фрейма на главном окне
    app = MainMenu(root)
    app.pack()

    # Настройка параметров главного окна
    root.title('ИВРО')
    root.width = 180
    root.height = 110
    root.x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    root.y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.geometry(f'{root.width}x{root.height}+{int(root.x - root.width / 2)}+{int(root.y - root.height / 2)}')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    root.mainloop()
```

And another one

```
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Введите заметку")
        self.btn = tk.Button(text='Hello')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(bg="darkgreen", fg='white')
        self.text.pack()
        self.geometry('800x800')
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


def show_notes_widget(): 
    notes_widget=NotesWidget()
    notes_widget.mainloop()
```

In my opinion the problem is here

```
def __init__(self):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1: It is because you did not specify the parent of the `Button` and `Text` widgets, so they will be children of the root window, not the `Toplevel` window.  You should specify the parent when creating them:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class NotesWidget(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Введите заметку")
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='Hello') # specify parent
        self.btn.pack()
        self.text = tk.Text(self, bg="darkgreen", fg='white') # specify parent
        self.text.pack()
        self.geometry('800x800')
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()


def show_notes_widget(): 
    notes_widget=NotesWidget()
    notes_widget.mainloop()
```

For case 2: It is because when you create the `Toplevel` window, the `root` window (instance of `Tk()`) will be created implicitly for you.